# Handle Ctrl+Z (undo/redo) for text editor in single page application

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, undo-redo, ctrl, kendo-editor

I have single page application which consists of a text editor (kendo Editor). The data in the text editor are replaced somewhat like this

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
                    resizable: {
                        content: false,
                        toolbar: true
                    }
                });

                var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");

                var setValue = function () {
                    editor.value($("#value").val());
                };
```

see demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/api).

The Issue:
So I am changing record of `A` then save it. Then I switch to `B`. Now if I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the text editor shows the record of `A`. How can I prevent this behavior.

Is a way to remove the undo history on demand, or something which would prevent the text editor replacing text with previous record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated: Better Solution.**

I contacted Kendo devs and they provided a neat solution.

```
var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
editor.undoRedoStack.clear();
```

> Note: this function is not documented in the public api and is
>   may change in newer version. This is working as of version
>   2016.3.1118

[demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ImiVO)

**Old Solution.**

I ended up destroying and rebinding the widget to the textarea.

http://dojo.telerik.com/OjIZe

```
$("#destroy").click(function(){ 
  var copy=$("#editor").clone(); 
  $("#editor").data('kendoEditor').wrapper.find("iframe").remove(); 
  $("#editor").data('kendoEditor').destroy(); 
  $("#test").empty(); 
  $("#test").append(copy); 
  $("#editor").kendoEditor({ resizable:    { 
    content: false, toolbar: true 
  } 
  }); 
});
```